# Angular 2 Router Data Binding Error

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I am building an application using Angular 2 Meteor, and am having a problem with data binding.  I have a very simple wrapper component configured, which has a router outlet for two routes (/a and /b) to two components (a and b).  After the user clicks a button on a, I use this.router.navigate(['B']) to change to the B component.

I have a one-way property binding configured inside the B component, which simply pulls the text property from the B class.  I can see this text if I were to navigate to example.com/b, but not if I am redirected from A to B using the this.router.navigate call.  Why is this the case?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: It's quite unclear what the question is about. Please provide more informatino.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/cemersoz/1f1724b4733543ca56aaf11b852d01dc

Comment: I am facing same problem. did you get the solution ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For those who are reading this now- this pertained to Angular Router 2. Angular Router 4 fixed this issue.

Comment: This is not considered an answer to the question. Please add a comment instead.

Comment: @Cyzanfar this is precisely an answer.  There was a bug and upgrading fixes the problem.

Comment: Yes my bad I actually didn;t see you answered your own question... Will remove my downvote. Sorry about that.